# Unable to stop the timer created using AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior

Tags: wicket, wicket-6, wicket-1.6

I am working on a single page wicket application. When ever user clicks on a Navigation Item a new Tab is opened. The requirement was to have two types of Panels one a normal one and another an Auto refresh panel.

I have a TabPanel class which extends from Panel which actually contains all the Tabs and methods to manage tabs like add, remove, set current.

Following is the customer timer that I have added to TabPanel.

```
private class AutoRefreshTimer extends AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior {
    public AutoRefreshTimer(Duration updateInterval) {
        super(updateInterval);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onTimer(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        Tab currentTab = getCurrentTab();
        if(currentTab != null) {
            if(currentTab.getPanel() instanceof AutoRefreshPanel) {
                AutoRefreshPanel ajaxRefreshPanel = (AutoRefreshPanel) currentTab.getPanel();
                ajaxRefreshPanel.onRefresh(target);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Following is the method to added the timer 'autoRefreshTimer' which is an instance variable in TabPanel class.

```
private void addNewAutoRefreshTimer(final Duration autoRefreshInterval) {
    autoRefreshTimer = new AutoRefreshTimer(autoRefreshInterval);
    add(autoRefreshTimer);
}
```

Following are the methods to control the timer:

```
public void startAutoRefreshTimer(final AjaxRequestTarget target, final Duration autoRefreshInterval) {
    if(!autoRefreshTimer.isStopped()) 
        addNewAutoRefreshTimer(autoRefreshInterval);
    autoRefreshTimer.restart(target);
}

public void stopAutoRefreshTimer(final AjaxRequestTarget target, final Duration autoRefreshInterval) {
    if(autoRefreshTimer.isStopped())
        addNewAutoRefreshTimer(autoRefreshInterval);
    autoRefreshTimer.stop(target);
}

public void toggleAutoRefreshTimer(final AjaxRequestTarget target){
    Tab currentTab = getCurrentTab();
    if(currentTab != null) {
        if(currentTab.getPanel() instanceof AutoRefreshPanel) {
            AutoRefreshPanel ajaxRefreshPanel = (AutoRefreshPanel)currentTab.getPanel();
            this.autoRefreshInterval = ajaxRefreshPanel.getAutoRefreshInterval();
            startAutoRefreshTimer(target, this.autoRefreshInterval);
            return;
        }
    }
    stopAutoRefreshTimer(target, this.autoRefreshInterval);
}
```

The timer starts and stops in my local server when ever the user switches between the tabs either opening a new, or switch to already opened, close current which selects the previous tab, or close another tab without switching from current. 
But when I test the same in our staging server which is in a remote location, the timer fails in following scenario.

**Following is the step which creates the issue in Remote:**

```
1. Open two Normal tabs.
2. Open a tab containing AutoRefreshPanel.
3. Close 1st or 2nd normal tab by keeping the tab containing AutoRefreshPanel active/current. This expect the timer to be
fired/running.
4. Switch to the remaining Normal tab. This stops the timer in local server but not in Remote.
```

Apart from the above mentioned step in all other scenarios the timer starts and stops as expected in both local and remote.

// UPDATE: I found a fix for this issue. But not sure is it the best one. Following is the changes that I have made:

```
private class AutoRefreshTimer extends AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior {
    public AutoRefreshTimer(Duration updateInterval) {
        super(updateInterval);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onTimer(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        Tab currentTab = getCurrentTab();
        if(currentTab != null) {
            if(currentTab.getPanel() instanceof AutoRefreshPanel) {
                AutoRefreshPanel ajaxRefreshPanel = (AutoRefreshPanel) currentTab.getPanel();
                ajaxRefreshPanel.onRefresh(target);
                return; // added return
            }
        }
        stop(target); // added a call to stop method.
    }
}

// Replaced startAutoRefreshTimer, stopAutoRefreshTimer and toggleAutoRefreshTimer with the following method:
public void manageAutoRefreshTimer(final AjaxRequestTarget target){
    Tab currentTab = getCurrentTab();
    if(currentTab != null) {
        if(currentTab.getPanel() instanceof AutoRefreshPanel) {
            AutoRefreshPanel ajaxRefreshPanel = (AutoRefreshPanel)currentTab.getPanel();
            this.autoRefreshInterval = ajaxRefreshPanel.getAutoRefreshInterval();
            if(!autoRefreshTimer.isStopped()) 
                addNewAutoRefreshTimer(autoRefreshInterval);
            autoRefreshTimer.restart(target);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What I find strange is that in both `start` and `stop` methods you add a new instance of the behavior to the component. This will add several timer behaviors.

Comment: I tried remove(Behavior) method but getting error.